# Cakephp simple OR condition

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to perform a simple OR statement with a Cakephp find.. can't manage to get this or condition to work quite right, consistently this tends to execute the first part of the statement and not the OR.. anyone offer any pointers?

```
    $hols = $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions'  => array(
            'Holiday.leave_type <>' =>3,
            'Holiday.user_id' => $userID,
            'Holiday.start >=' => $firstDayThisMonth,
            'Holiday.start <=' => $lastDayThisMonth
        ),
        'OR' => array(
            'Holiday.leave_type' =>3,
            'Holiday.active' => 1,
            'Holiday.user_id' => null,
            'Holiday.start >=' => $firstDayThisMonth,
            'Holiday.start <=' => $lastDayThisMonth
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OR` operator works on child arrays only. So to express the rule `A OR B` you would have to write `'conditions'=>array('OR'=>array(array(A),array(B)))`

The conditions for your where clause would be:

```
$hols = $this->find('all', array(
    'conditions'  => array(
        'OR'=>array(
            array(
               'Holiday.leave_type <>' =>3,
               'Holiday.user_id' => $userID,
               'Holiday.start >=' => $firstDayThisMonth,
               'Holiday.start <=' => $lastDayThisMonth
            ),
            array(
               'Holiday.leave_type' =>3,
               'Holiday.active' => 1,
               'Holiday.user_id' => null,
               'Holiday.start >=' => $firstDayThisMonth,
               'Holiday.start <=' => $lastDayThisMonth
            )
        )
    )
)
```

You could simplify this to be:

```
$hols = $this->find('all', array(
    'conditions'  => array(
        'Holiday.start BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($firstDayThisMonth,$lastDayThisMonth),
        'OR'=>array(
            array(
               'Holiday.leave_type <>' =>3,
               'Holiday.user_id' => $userID,
            ),
            array(
               'Holiday.leave_type' =>3,
               'Holiday.active' => 1,
               'Holiday.user_id' => null
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Duh. Plus the refactoring makes sense. Thanks.